# Install dc in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, dc

How to install `dc` (desktop calculator) in Cygwin?

`dc` is not found among Cygwin packages. Should it be compiled from the sources? What is the proper way?

Comment: Perhaps this question better fits [Superuser](https://superuser.com/), but superuser doesn't even have the `[dc]` tag.  Actually, `dc` is a toy for the programmers only ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dc` is included into the package of `bc` (basic calculator). See the list of [installed binaries](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fbc%2Fbc-1.06.95-2&grep=calculator) at [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/packages/) website.

So, the command to install `dc` is:

```
apt-cyg install bc
```

Answer (score 0):

dc is wrong in cygwin. The command `dc -e "2i B.Cp"` does a number clamping to `1.5`, which is default in `bc` but not in `dc`. The correct value would be `17`.

Do not install it.

Comment: It seems, you rely on an undefined behavior when you uses B and C digits in the binary input radix. Try `16i B.Cp`, it prints 11.7